# How can I select a default category for bootstrap portfolio

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a portfolio section on the website I'm working on. As a default, it currently shows every item.

I've removed the "All" button, but now I want it to show a specific category on load rather than everything. Below is my HTML and the JS

```
    <div class="sort" align="center">
<!--            <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="all">All</button>-->
        <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="drinks">Vending Machines</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="chips">Vending Machine Parts</button>
    </div>
    <br/><br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>

        <div class="gallery_product col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 filter drinks">
            <div class="productimgwrap">
            <img src="images/products/drinks/canned-regular-cola.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="gallery_product col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 filter chips">
            <div class="productimgwrap">
            <img src="images/products/chips/lays-oven-baked-originals-chip.jpg" class="img-responsive"> </div>
        </div>

        <div class="gallery_product col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 filter drinks">
            <div class="productimgwrap">
            <img src="images/products/drinks/canned-diet-cola.jpg" class="img-responsive"> </div>
        </div>

        <div class="gallery_product col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 filter candy">
            <div class="productimgwrap">
            <img src="images/products/candy/Hershey-chocolate-bar---plain.jpg" class="img-responsive"> </div>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    


$(".filter-button").click(function(){
    var value = $(this).attr('data-filter');

    if(value == "all")
    {                       
        $('.filter').removeClass('hidden');
        $('.filter').show('0');
    }
    else
    {
        $('.filter[filter-item="'+value+'"]').removeClass('hidden');
        $(".filter").not('.filter[filter-item="'+value+'"]').addClass('hidden');
        $(".filter").not('.'+value).hide('3000');
        $('.filter').filter('.'+value).show('3000');

    }
});

if ($(".filter-button").removeClass("active")) {
$(this).removeClass("active");
}
$(this).addClass("active");


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your categories are, but couldn't you just add `$('button[data-filter="drinks"]').click()` to the end of your `$(document).ready(...)` function?

That way, when the script is done executing, the button will be invoked, thus showing your category.

Comment: Yes...yes I could. I knew it was something small. Thank you!